# How to get view in controller then render data and pass it to ajax

Tags: ajax, view, laravel-5.7

The question is how to get the view and store all the html in a variable then render the data to it's table cells then send it complete ready html to ajax so I can put it where ever I want. I am implementing search functionality.
I know one way that I put all the html manually in a variable in my controller function and then pass it to but that will be to much for one function, Is there any smart way of doing it?

```
public function search_ajax(Request $request)
{

    $cat_id = $request->input('category');
    $records['records'] = DB::table('bookmark_models')->get();

  // here I am expecting to render my data to view and send it to ajax
    $view = view("search/records", $records);
  // loading html view like this is necessary because I have pagination links also there. 
  // in view {{$records->links()}}

    return $view;

}
```

it is doing like that see the picture please

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$view = view("search/records",compact('records'))->render();
return $view;
```

Comment: I try that but It shows the result same as picture I show above

Comment: Please post your base blade, extending blade and ajax request